# Custom InputFormatter on PostAsync exception in ASP NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a strange problem that I don't know why is giving problems:

On client, I have this code:

```
 HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("http://127.0.0.1:5544/api/Blablabla", new StringContent("test"));
```

On server, I have implemented a custom InputFormatter that have this

```
 public async override Task<InputFormatterResult> ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context)
    {
        var request = context.HttpContext.Request;

        try
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(request.Body))
            {
                var content = await reader.ReadToEndAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                return await InputFormatterResult.SuccessAsync(content).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return await InputFormatterResult.FailureAsync();
        }            
    }
```

If I try this, the catch exception of the server is fired, giving me an exception of:

An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

But.....

If in the client I make the PostAsync "sync" doing this:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = _httpClient.PostAsync("http://127.0.0.1:5544/api/Blablabla", new StringContent("test")).Result;
```

Everything works ok.

What's the problem???

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I fixed it...

The problem was, as you can imagine, that the function that called postasync was async, but the one before was not, and I did not make a .Wait() to that one.

Was nothing related to asp net core, just a problem of async code from sync code.